# ListView not full width

Tags: android, xml, listview

I created a ListView Item in my Frame Layout:

home_activity.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Home">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/home_item_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
</ListView>
</FrameLayout>
```

home_list_item.xml:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/home_item_activity_selector_textview"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:paddingLeft="15dp"
/>
```

My proble is that the ListView item is not 100% of screen width, only the width of the label

What I have to change?

[image]

Comment: `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`?

Comment: @njzk2 no, i tried every possiblility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove `android:gravity="center_vertical"` on `ListView` and set `android:layout_width="match_parent"` instead of `wrap_content` on `TextView`.

Comment: Could you attach screenshot?

Comment: added screenshot, you can see my touch, it's impossible to touch on the non-gray area

Comment: In your home_activity.xml, change width of the FrameLayout to fill_parent. hope it works

Comment: @PratibhaS `fill_parent` is deprecated name of `match_parent`.

Comment: @PratibhaS no, unfortunately not

Comment: The answer from Basyl Glodan is correct! home_list_item to match_parent

Comment: @SeseSchneider It's the same as my answer. Please read it carefully.

Answer (score 1):

In your `home_list_item.xml` change

`android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

to

`android:layout_width="match_parent"`

Comment: I agree. Based on the information given by the OP, this is the most likely solution

Comment: I think there is a bug, sometimes it workes, sometimes not

Comment: I suggested exact the same solution in my answer.